# Token name and icon are not showing on explorers

Tags: solana-program, spl-token, metaplex, token-2022, mpl-token-metadata

The token name and icon are not showing on Solana explorers:

https://explorer.solana.com/address/3Gx8FbPiWfSdgXoBMzT4r22n9nhyF5CiRv52qf3WhEL8
https://solscan.io/token/3Gx8FbPiWfSdgXoBMzT4r22n9nhyF5CiRv52qf3WhEL8
https://solana.fm/address/3Gx8FbPiWfSdgXoBMzT4r22n9nhyF5CiRv52qf3WhEL8

The metadata is shown on SolanaFM and token name and icon are showing fine in Phantom wallet.

The token was created using the Token22 program and the metadata was added directly to the mint account as described in the documentation:

https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#metadata

Is something wrong with the token metadata? Way it is not showing in explorers? How to fix that?

Answer (score 3):

The token extensions are pretty new and not yet supported everywhere. Feel free to nag all the wallets and explorers to support metadata and transfer hooks :D Im pretty sure many are working on adding support already.